# Warning using format string with sprintf

Tags: c

```
    uint16_t foo;
    char     str[ 32 ];
    sprintf( str, "%6u", foo )
```

The previous code snippet throws a warning: *#181 argument is incompatible with corresponding format string*.

How would you get rid of that warning?

Peter

Answer (score 4):

"%u" is for `unsigned`, not `uint16_t`. You want something like:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

sprintf(str, "%6" PRIu16, foo);
```

Answer (score 3):

Either cast your `uint16_t` to `unsigned int`, or replace `"%6u"` with `"%6" PRIu16`. That requires the header `inttypes.h` to be included.

Answer (score 1):

The `%u` format directive takes an argument of type `unsigned int`, which on your platform is probably bigger than 16 bits. On a 32-bit machine, a `uint16_t` will generally correspond to an `unsigned short`, which is printed with the `%hu` directive.

However, the reason for using the [`stdint.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7999959899/basedefs/stdint.h.html) types in the first place is portability. The (also standard) [`inttypes.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/basedefs/inttypes.h.html) header file defines macros which contain the appropriate format directives for each `stdint.h` type for the current platform. In this case, the macro is called `PRIu16`, which can be used like so:

```
sprintf( str, "%6" PRIu16, foo );
```

Comment: I have included inttypes.h which defines them.

Comment: I thought the uint16_t represents an unsigned 16 bit value - regardless of the cpu bus or the operating system. I use the intel c++ compiler which does not deliver a stdint.h header.

Comment: @user3149989: You are correct; perhaps my wording was a little ambiguous. `uint16_t` always defines an unsigned 16 bit value. It is the size of `unsigned short` which varies depending on the platform. On 32-bit x86 platforms, an `unsigned short` happens also to be 16 bits, but the `%u` directive expects a value the size of an `unsigned int`, which on this platform is 32 bits. The `stdint.h` and `inttypes.h` headers were both introduced in C99 as far as I am aware a conforming implementation should provide both. However, as `inttypes.h` is a superset of `stdint.h` only the former is required.